# How to use various fonts on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use trainway font on my website. But i am pretty sure that the user wont be having it installed in his machine.

So is there a way to display the text of a particular font without prompting the user to install that font.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Mo' Bulletproofer Method](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) by Paul Irish et co.

Also, try FontSquirrels' [@font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to see what the generated syntax is for a font and convert some freely available fonts for use on the web.

Comment: Thanks for the information the link was very useful for what exactly i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't (afaik) a *Javascript* solution to your problem, but you can use the CSS command `@font-face`

Comment: Actually, there is - **cufon**, as @amosrivera stated. Uses VML/SVG for font rendering by converting fonts to paths.

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, it uses Javascript/VML/SVG to replace the native font-rendering of the browser.  Whom the gods would destroy, they first make mad.

Answer (score 2):

IF you have a the proper license for the typeface you can embed it with `@font-face` which can work cross browser provided you have the rights to take the font an convert it.

There are also tools like [Cufon](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about) and sIFR that use flash or JS to emebed and use fonts. CUFON i think you still need a license to convert to its format for embedding... sIFR really gets around the licensing since it being embedded in a flash movie.

Answer (score 2):

You can use other online services like [google font API](http://code.google.com/webfonts) or [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) that only request you add some extra code. Although am not sure if you will find that specific font.

Comment: No the font that i am looking for is not in the google webfonts but there are few of them that i can make use of. Thanks